# Is there a general way to find a $f(x)$ such that $f(x+1)/f(x)=2,~f(0)=A$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I know a function that satifies $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=2,~f(0)=A$ is $f(x)=A\cdot 2^x$. However, that is because this question is arise in a chapter of exponentiation in a junior-high school textbook, so I can successfully guess it. However, is there a general way to find the unknown function given by such functional equations? Is this related to differential equations?

PS: The question is: If the amount of a kind of bacteria will double every month, and if the original amount is $A$, then write the amount function with respect to  month.

Comment: Do you want $f$ to be continuous (from your application, I would say yes)?  If that's not necessary, you can define values for all of $[0,1)$ and make a function out of those.

Comment: I would like to see in both situation how to solve this question(what do you mean to define values for all of $[0,1)$ and make a function out of those?). Thank you!

Comment: What Michael means, if I'm not mistaking is that you're given data which doubles after a month or lets say $30$ days for clarity, but you don't have any idea what happens on first day,  on second day, what happens after each hour etc. So you can make that data up for every value which isn't a month in your example for each value which isn't $0,1,2,3..$ a positive integer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting your request for $x \in \mathbb{N}$, rather than $x \in \mathbb{R}$; Michael Burr's answer covers the real case.

---

Functional equations are in general not easy to solve, but there are various techniques. For your particular example, just list out the first few values of $f$, spot that they look like powers of $2$, and prove by induction that they are powers of $2$.

A more systematic approach to your question might involve generating functions. Consider $$F(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) y^n$$
(treating this sum purely formally, without considering questions of convergence; as long as we never attempt to evaluate $F$ at any value of $y$, our resulting manipulations are safe whether or not the sums converge).

Then $$F(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2 f(n-1) y^n = 2y \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n-1) y^{n-1} = 2y (f(0) + F(y))$$
where for the first step we used that $f(n) = 2 f(n-1)$, and for the last step we used that $$f(0) + F(y) = f(0) \times y^0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)y^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) y^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n-1) y^{n-1}$$

Therefore $$F(y)(1-2y) = 2y f(0) = 2yA$$
so $$F(y) = \frac{2y}{1-2y} A$$

Finally, $f(n)$ is the coefficient of $y^n$ in that expression, which is easy by the binomial expansion of $(1-2y)^{-1}$: it's $A \times 2^n$.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ has a recursive formula which shows that the answer is $A2^n$.  That might be nice to add.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if the original question is like mine, the domain of the function that author want is only in integer or in real numbers(of course, positive real numbers)? I don't know the custom.

Comment: @Eric From the context, it looks like they want an answer only for natural $x$. The letter $x$ usually denotes a real variable in this context, but the question is about a number of bacteria (which is an integer). Also, the recurrence relation only relates $f(x)$ to $f(x+1)$ - and hence the value of $f$ at $1$ (say) tells us nothing at all about its value at $\frac{1}{2}$. So it makes most sense (to me) to interpret it as asking about $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Oops, sorry, I'm not sure the original question took bacteria for example, maybe it took the area of bacteria for example(in this case, it could be real). I just remember the demand on $f$. My fault. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $g:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be any function such that $g(0)=A$.  Then, we can define $f$ as follows:
$$
f(x)=2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}g(x-\lfloor x\rfloor).
$$
In this case, 
$$
\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=\frac{2^{\lfloor x+1\rfloor}g((x+1)-\lfloor x+1\rfloor)}{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}g(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}=\frac{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}g((x+1)-(\lfloor x\rfloor+1))}{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}g(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}
=\frac{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}g(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}{2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}g(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}=2.
$$
So, there are lots of possible functions.  If you want $f$ to be continuous, then $g$ must be continuous.  As you add more conditions, like differentiability, there are additional restrictions on $g$.

Comment: How did you come up with this example? So smart!

Answer (score 0):

Discretization of continuous dynamical system
$$\dot{x}=\ln2\cdot x$$
is 
$$x\left(t\right)=e^{\ln{2} \cdot t}x_{0}$$
or
$$x_{t+1}=2^{t+1}x_{0}=2x_{t}$$
So, your equation $f\left(x+1\right)=2f\left(x\right)$ is just a discretization of the differential equation 
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\ln2\cdot f\left(x\right)$$